# the function passed is not working with jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I tried to make a function by passing an event to a button but it is not working. What I want the function to do is that when the button is clicked show in the DOM that I click and also display with the innerhtml a message on the web page using if/ else depending of the user imput in the imputs of time abd weight

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calculate').on('click', function() {
    $('#calculate ul li input').slideToggle(800);
  });

  /********************************************************/
  var gender = $('#gender');
  var age = $('#age');
  var time = $('#time');
  var weigth = $('#weight');
  var result = $('#result');
  var calculate = $('#calculate');


  if (calculate.lenght) {
    /*event listener*/
    calculate.on('click', calculateF);
    /*para que cuando se haga click se active la funcion calcular
    que estoy creando abajo*/

    function calculateF(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("click");

      var timeVal = parseInt(time.val());
      var weightVal = parseInt(weight.val());

      if (time > 8 && weight > 25) {
        result.html(" text ");

      } else {
        result.html("text");
      }


    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="manejo_cargas" id="manejo_cargas">
  <h3>calculate work load</h3>
</div>

<section id="calculate">
  <div class="calculate">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Gender" id="gender"></li>
      <li><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="age" id="age"></li>
      <li><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="time" id="time"></li>
      <li><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="weight" id="weight"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>


<div class="calculate">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="result" id="calculate">
</div>

<!--here comes the result-->
<div class="result" id="result">

</div>
```

.

Comment: where is the html that is used with your javascript, add it in the question by editing

Comment: Do you really have tags named "time", "weight", "result" etc ..? Notice also, that `if ($('calculate'))` will always pass, `$` returns a jQuery object no matter if any elements would be not found by the selector.

Comment: You are probably supposed to use `var calculate = $('#result');` (for the id) or `var calculate = $('.result');` (if you used a class). (edit: forgot the dot)

Comment: can you post the HTML please?

Comment: also there's no point if checking `if(calculate.length)`...Yeah you save an event listener...but I think it's pretty much pointless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `#` if you have declared the `time`, `weight`, `result`, and `calculate` as id's of the elements that you are targeting.

From what I can guess is that the `weight` and `time` are inputs the `result` is a `div` and the `calculate` is the `button` to be clicked.

I will assume they are ids so you need to add `#` before the id when specifying selectors in jquery using `$()` otherwise use `.` if they are class names.

Then if you are converting the code to jquery from javascript you need to replace the respective functions like `addEventListener` `.innerHtml` , `.value` etc

You can see the working below but the calculations and the message that you have to add is on your end as you never provided any details so i have made the conversion for the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var time = $('#time');
  var weight = $('#weight');
  var result = $('#result');
  var calculate = $('#calculate');



  /*event listener*/
  calculate.on('click', calculateF);

  function calculateF(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("you hit click");
    /*new variables*/
    var timeVal = parseInt(time.val());
    var weightVal = parseInt(weight.val());

    if (time > 8 && weight > 25) {
      result.html(" if condition true ").show();
    } else {
      result.html("message from the else part").show();
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.result {
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--here comes the result-->
<div class="result" id="result">

</div>
<div class="manejo_cargas" id="manejo_cargas">
  <h3>calculate work load</h3>
</div>

<section>
  <div class="calculate">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Gender" id="gender"></li>
      <li><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="age" id="age"></li>
      <li><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="time" id="time"></li>
      <li><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="weight" id="weight"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>


<div class="calculate">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="result" id="calculate">
</div>


<!--folder where my jquery code is saved-->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!--folder where my jquery code is saved-->
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

## `EDIT`

Your HTML has duplicate `id` `calculate` for the `section` and for the `input` button that's why it isn't working you cannot have multiple elements with the same id I have used your HTML and removed the id from the `section` tag, see the demo above

Comment: hello thaks for your help I tried to fix the problems I have but is not working, now I post the html code and the jquery code with your correction but I cant make it work.Please can you check my code and help me.

Comment: @CarlosZavala see the **edit** section in my answer and mark the answer as correct if it works for you

Comment: thanks for your time and your response. I finally made it :)